# How to fit exponential regression in r?(a.k.a changing power of base)

Tags: r, time-series, linear-regression, forecasting, exponential

I am making exponential regressions in r.

Actually I want to compare `y = exp^(ax+b)` with `y = 5^(ax+b)`.

```
# data 
set.seed(1)
y <- c(3.5, 2.9, 2.97,4.58,6.18,7.11,9.50,9.81,10.17,10.53,
       12.33,14.14,18, 22, 25, 39, 40, 55, 69, 72) + rnorm(20, 10, 1)
x <- 1:length(y)


df = data.frame(x = x, y = y)
predata = data.frame(x = 1:20)

# plot
plot(df, ylim = c(0,100), xlim = c(0,40))


# simple linear regression
fit_sr = lm(y~x, data = df)
pre_sr = predict(fit_sr, newdata = predata, 
                 interval ='confidence',
                 level = 0.90)
lines(pre_sr[,1], col = "red")

# exponential regression 1
fit_er1 = lm(log(y, base = exp(1))~x, data = df)
pre_er1 = predict(fit_er1, newdata = predata, 
                  interval ='confidence',
                  level = 0.90)
pre_er1 = exp(1)^pre_er1 # correctness
lines(pre_er1[,1], col = "dark green")


# exponential regression 2
fit_er2 = lm(log(y, base = 5) ~ x, data = df)
pre_er2 = predict(fit_er2, newdata = predata, 
                  interval ='confidence',
                  level = 0.90)
pre_er2 = 5^pre_er2 # correctness
lines(pre_er2[,1], col = "blue")
```

I expect something like this(plot1), but exponential regression 1 and 2 are totally the same(plot2).
plot1
[image]

plot2
[image]

The two regression should be different because of the Y value is different. 
Also, I am looking for how to make `y = exp(ax+b) + c fitting` in R.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Your code is correct, your theory is where the problem is. The models should be the same.

Easiest way is to think on the log scale, as you've done in your code. Starting with `y = exp(ax + b)` we can get to `log(y) = ax + b`, so a linear model with `log(y)` as the response. With `y = 5^(cx + d)`, we can get `log(y) = (cx + d) * log(5) = (c*log(5)) * x + (d*log(5))`, also a linear model with `log(y)` as the response. Yhe model fit/predictions will not be any different with a different base, you can transform the base `e` coefs to base `5` coefs by multiplying them by `log(5)`. `a = c*log(5)` and `b = d*log(5)`.

It's a bit like wanting to compare the linear models y = ax + b where `x` is measured in meters vs y = ax + b where `x` is measured in centimeters. The coefficients will change to accommodate the scale, but the fit isn't any different.

Comment: Upvoted for the clarity and excellence of the answer.

Comment: @Gregor 
I really thank your kind answer. I've got what I have mistaken! Very nice solution!

Answer (score 2):

The first part is already answered by [@gregor](https://stackoverflow.com/a/57881662/10488504), the second part *"...I am looking for how to make `y = exp(ax+b) + c` fitting in R"* can be done with `nls`:

```
fit_er3  <-  nls(y ~ exp(a*x+b) + c, data = df, start=list(a=1,b=0,c=0))
```

Comment: @ Gki I reall appreciate your answer too!! thank you a lot!